# Do I build Ruby documentation in Ubuntu ? Or should I simply move past this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While navigating through http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/linux  I made it to step 4 and instead of `rvm install 2.3` I used `rvm install 2.4.4` in the Ubuntu command prompt and everything ran fine. Once output was finished, the last two lines said: 
 `Install of ruby-2.4.4 - #complete 
Ruby was built without documentation, to build it run: rvm docs generate-ri` 
 What do you fine people think? Build or not?
 The above link is meant to be part of an installation process for The Odin Project, which is just a free online web dev course if that helps put things into perspective.

Comment: Number of times I've used the built-in documentation for Ruby since 2005: Zero. The web-based versions are always better. That documentation is only relevant if you know you're going offline for some time, and in that case a printed book is probably better.

Comment: @tadman THANK YOU!!! I've been stuck waiting to get an appropriate response before moving ahead for a few hours now and have commented on numerous sites. Thanks again, that's a huge help!!

Answer (score 0):

I use RubyMine. When I'm curious about a method, such as `render`, I put the text caret on it and hit Control+B. RubyMine takes me to the method's definition, where I can read the comment which generates that documentation.

I always build Ruby and Gems with full documentation, and I never bother to read their output...

Comment: Could you quickly catch up on this conversation I had today ? <https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045780/problem-with-rails-installfest-what-do-i-enter-to-correct-issue-libreadline6-d/1045987#1045987>  The issue started yesterday, and I started getting caught up today through the help of someone online and then they disappeared. Is it possible to review that quick exchange as it is the preface for this question and helps illuminate what exactly I'm trying to do which I have a hard time explaining being a newbie haha.

Comment: You can set up a `~/.gemrc` with flags to skip generating documentation. Makes installing gems *much* faster.

Comment: @tadman based on what you may have picked up in this thread and the link directly above, would you say it's best to use `~/.gemrc`? I personally don't mind wait times if I know nothing will be messed up and everything will function properly.

Comment: You can use that file to set defaults for your installs, and you can always override as necessary if/when that's an issue. As most people use `bundle install` it's less of a problem these days, but still useful.